Example of docker-compose.minimal.example.yml
I'm trying to install using docker compose photoview on Raspberry PI.
I read that this compose file should be enough to start it locally
https://github.com/photoview/photoview/blob/master/docker-compose%20example/docker-compose.minimal.example.yml
but it doesn't work
Can some one help me and propose me a working docker-compose.yml file?
Thank you
Andrea
